# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined - react testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I keep getting this error whenever I run my tests. I'm using react-testing-library.

[failed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Zcm.png)

Here is my code and page I'm trying to test:
[api call and map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sSLp.png)

my test: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4B3E.png)

I'm honestly not sure why its failing there, the page renders fine but the test won't pass and the screenshot above isn't very informative? Apologies if this isn't detailed enough? any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the code as plain text instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `data[index].field` is `undefined`. Your test is trying to access the property `name` on `undefined` which is a `TypeError`.

I see that `data` comes from `getKnowledgePageCategories` which you are mocking in your tests. I would suggest logging what value you're returning in your mock, most likely the error is there.